# JIRA jql Query - what * means?

Tags: jira, wildcard, jql

There is no regexp in JQL:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/138055/how-can-i-use-regex-in-a-jql-query-i-cannot-match-strings-that-have-a-specific-ending-in-jql-ex-ing-should-match-running-jogging-etc

What is the meaning of * in a jql Query?, I have different results when using and not using it. But I didn't find any consequence in the results.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`~` means CONTAINS, so

```
summary ~ win
```

means *WHERE summary CONTAINS the exact word win*.
`*` is a wildcard. The example:

```
summary ~ "win*"
```

means *WHERE summary CONTAINS win and any multiple character combination after it*.

There are two types of wild-cards in JQL: `?` and `*` where:

1. To perform a single character wildcard search use the "?" symbol.
2. To perform a multiple character wildcard search use the "*" symbol.

Check the [JIRA advanced searching guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching) and the [wild-card explanation here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Performing+Text+Searches).

Comment: works not for every field. For example, `fixVersion ~ 1.4.*` returns error `The operator '~' is not supported by the 'fixVersion' field.`, at least in Jira 6.0.4

Comment: For version fields like `fixVersion` and `affectedVersion` you have to use the `versionMatch()` function, e.g. `fixVersion in versionMatch("15.2.*")`.

Comment: Doesn't work for sprint~"Yamaha*" . Returns error "The operator '~' is not supported by the 'sprint' field."

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian calls the '~' operator "contains", but it doesn't actually mean "contains".  For example, searching the Customer field (a custom text field) for "ABCD" will return a hit for "ABCD, EFGH" but not for "EFGH, ABCD".  And you can't use the wildcard character * at the start of the search string.  See [wildcard searches](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/performing-text-searches-720416596.html) and [JRASERVER-6218](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-6218) for more.  We're investigating [Adaptavist ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview) to work around this 12 year-old bug.